# translate python function with yield(string) to C++

Tags: python, c++, function, yield, translate

I'm translating a python function into a C++ function; this function uses a `yield(string)` statement that I don't know how to translate.

Here the whole story...I have a certain function that reads an input ASCII file `filename`, which contains lines of data, and puts the content of the file into an `std::vector`. When reading this input file (in another function respect with the one showed below), I need to jump a bunch of lines (5 or 6, it depends on the input file's name) and, for this purpose, I define a function, the `file_struct_generator`, which marks as "data" the data lines and as "unused" the data lines I don't need. I need something similar to this function in C++, and in particular, I need something similar to `yield(string)` (pay attention, `string`!), but in C++ of course. Here I show you the lines of the code I need to "translate" from python to C++. How can I rewrite `yield("unused")` and `yield("data")` in C++? Or if `yield` is unusable in C++, can I write a similar function in C++ using something different which works as a generator? Thanks for helping me!

```
def file_struct_generator(filename):
    if "more" in filename:
        bad_line_number = 5
    else:
        bad_line_number = 6

    yield("data")
    for i in range(bad_line_number):
        yield("unused")
    while True:
        yield("data")
```

**EDIT:**
I do not use C++20, but C++11. I tried @Arthur Tacca code and it works for my purpose, thank you all.

Comment: You can use co-routines from C++20 to do this, but before that maybe you could get the same functionality in this case with function local static variables.

Comment: Although newer versions of C++ have coroutines which let you do something pretty much like this, your easiest path is almost certainly going to be to make a class. You'll need member variables to hold the state, including `filename` and `i` of course but also how far you are through the function (have you returned `"data"` yet or not? Have you finished the first loop?). Then add a method called something like `getNext()` that checks the state, updates it, then returns the next result.

Comment: @ArthurTacca sounds nice. Can you help me to write this thing? In the function which reads the data lines, after satisfying certain conditions, what I want to do for sure is:
file_struct= file_struct_generator(); what_line=next(file_struct). Thank you if you'll help me.

Comment: I think you don't need ```yield``` at all. Could you please provide reproducible example in python?

Comment: @Suthiro how would you return infinite `"data"` without `yield`?

Comment: @fslack Were any of the answers helpful? My answer is a state machine in a class, as you requested.

Comment: @Caleth I don't see anything infinite here. The "file" is always finite. As I understand, it is enough just to have a counter and a simple if-else statement. If the variable is less than counter, skip or handle "unused". Else - process "data".

Comment: @Suthiro And if you presented me code that did that, I'd reject it in review, and ask for a generator. By your logic, all you need is `while`, `+`, `-`, `=` and `is 0`, or an equivalent minimal sublanguage

Comment: @Caleth In the end, your answer is a comparison of counter and a variable wrapped in class. I don't understand why one is not recommended to wrap it in a function or a simple loop.

Comment: @ArthurTacca I'm testing what you posted, but it still doesn't work as I want. Could it be useful if I post the whole code in C++, including the part where I read the ASCII file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a state machine that reproduces that generator's functionality.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class FileStructIterator {
public:
    explicit FileStructIterator(const std::string& filename): 
        m_filename(filename), m_state(STATE_START) 
    {}

    std::string getNext() {
        switch (m_state) {
        case STATE_START:
            m_state = STATE_LOOP1;
            if (m_filename.find("more") != std::string::npos) {
                m_badLineNumber = 5;
            } else {
                m_badLineNumber = 6;
            }
            m_i = 0;
            return "data";

        case STATE_LOOP1:
            ++m_i;
            if (m_i >= m_badLineNumber) {
                m_state = STATE_LOOP2;
            }            
            return "unused";

        case STATE_LOOP2:
            return "data";

        default:
            throw std::logic_error("bad state");
        }
    }

private:
    std::string m_filename;

    enum State { STATE_START, STATE_LOOP1, STATE_LOOP2 };
    State m_state;

    size_t m_badLineNumber;
    size_t m_i;
};
```

Here's an example of using it (in this case I limited the output to the first 10 results so it doesn't loop forever).

```
int main() {
    auto it = FileStructIterator("nomore.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::string nextValue = it.getNext();
        std::cout << nextValue << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: In C++, `getNext` is traditionally split into two parts named `operator++` and `operator*`

Comment: @Caleth Unless you specifically need a iterator that conforms to the STL's iterator requirements, I don't see the point of complicating the interface like that. But that would certainly work too.

Comment: Add a `begin` and `end` and you can use `for ( : )`

Comment: @Caleth That is nice, but it's not outrageously better than `while (true) { auto x = y.getNext(); ...}`. Especially in this case where it's an infinite sequence so you probably need a parallel iteration anyway.

Comment: BTW the difference in complexity is not that great here, but if the iterator was doing something more complex then having separate methods might mean you need to cache the result in the object for later calls to  `operator*`. For example if you're reading lines from a file then the state alone is not enough to reproduce the yielded value (and I suspect reading from a file is what the OP is really doing and has given a dumbed down example).

Comment: @eerorika Output iterators are for writing, not reading. You could make it an input iterator but to satisfy the requirements of that it must return the same thing if you call `operator*` multiple times without a call to `operator++`, so you really do have to split the functionality. In my view, this whole discussion about standard iterator requirements is evidence that you should avoid the standard iterator interface if you want to write a little iterator class for one-off use.

Comment: Input iterators are explicitly allowed to return values, not references. All that is required is that you can dereference multiple times

Comment: @Caleth Yes, that's what I was trying to say, sorry if I wasn't being clear. That means that if your iterator is reading values from a file then it needs to cache the last value read from the file, or record where it is in the file to allow that to be read. Even in this simple example, you can see that your snippet is less straightforward than mine. I totally agree that there are times that satisfying the formal iterator requirements is worthwhile, but I would also say there are times when it's just not worth it at all. If you use your iterator class once in some private code, keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

> translate python function with yield(string) to C++

Prior to C++20, I don't think there is a simple, exact translation.

An alternative is to write a function template that accepts a functor:

```
template<class Yield>
void file_struct_generator(const std::string& filename, const Yield& yield)
{
    // ...
    yield("unused")
    // ...
```

This way the caller can provide a functor that deals with the output in a way they want to use it. They can provide for example one that prints the values, or another that stores the values in a container.

Crucially, this alternative is not lazy, and you cannot have an infinite loop like in the python code. Whether this is a useful translation depends on how the generator is used in Python. This is good for cases where the entire sequence is consumed.

---

I think this would be a direct translation in C++20:

```
generator<std::string>
file_struct_generator(const std::string& filename)
{
    bad_line_number = filename.find("more") != std::string::npos
        ? 5
        : 6;

    co_yield "data";
    for (int i : std::views::iota(0, bad_line_number))
        co_yield "unused";
    for(;;)
        co_yield "data";
}
```

Not tested due to lack of conforming compilers. Also the standard doesn't provide the `generator` type.

Comment: To deal with the problem of the infinite sequence: you could either throw an exception from the yield function and catch it higher up the call stack, or you could make it return a bool and instead of writing `yield(val)` write `if(yield(val)) return;`

Answer (score 1):

From C++20 you can use co-routines, you can achieve similar functionality to the python snippet with some thread_local variables (that are static):

```
std::string file_struct_generator(std::string filename) 
{
  thread_local int bad_line_number = filename.find("more") != std::string::npos ? 5 : 6;

  thread_local int i = 0;

  if (i++ && i <= bad_line_number) 
    return "unused";

  return "data";
}
```

Note that, as pointed out by ArthurTacca in the comments, this function can't actually be called with a different file-name, or at least, it won't start a new loop if you do that.

Comment: This isn't a coroutine. The python code is one call that returns a sequence of values

Comment: @Caleth I think the idea is for this `file_struct_generator` to be called in a loop, which would generate the sequence.

Comment: @Caleth Oh, maybe I'm misunderstanding what the python code is doing. I thought you had to keep calling the function, but control flow resumed from the `yield`.

Comment: @Caleth Under the hood, that sequence of values is really calling a function multiple times and resuming in the middle, not so differently than this (but you don't need to write out the state machine yourself). This answer reproduces that fine. The problem is not that you need to call it multiple times. The problem is that you can never reset it with another filename to start a new loop! (Plus it's not thread safe)

Comment: This is also missing the first "data" in the sequence, which comes before "unused".

Comment: @ArthurTacca That's what the `if(i++` check is for :)

Comment: ha! I missed that!

Comment: @ArthurTacca I made it thread safe as well, as eeorika pointed out :) You're right, I can't think of an obvious way to be able to call it with a different filename.

Comment: @eerorika I made them `thread_local` as suggested, thanks.

Comment: @ArthurTacca yes, there is an object, created from the body of the function, who's `next()` is being called

Comment: @Caleth Well, yes, this isn't *actually* a co-routine. Is the phrasing of the answer better now? I added a caveat to the solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 this would use `co_yield`. Prior to that you can write an iterator.

```
class file_struct_iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, std::string, std::ptrdiff_t, const std::string *, std::string> {
    enum class State {
        initial,
        bad_lines,
        remainder
    }

    State state = State::initial;
    size_t bad_line_number = 0;

public:

    file_struct_iterator(std::string filename) 
        : bad_line_number((filename.find("more") != filename.end()) ? 5 : 6)
    {}

    std::string operator*() {
        switch (state) {
            case State::initial:
            case State::remainder: return "data";
            case State::bad_lines: return "unused";
        }
    }

    file_struct_iterator& operator++() {
        switch (state) {
            case State::initial: state = State::bad_lines; break;
            case State::bad_lines: if (--bad_line_number == 0) { state = remainder; } break;
            case State::remainder: break;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    file_struct_iterator operator++(int) {
        file_struct_iterator retval = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return retval;
    }

    bool operator==(file_struct_iterator other) const {
        return (state == other.state) && (bad_line_number == other.bad_line_number);
    }
    
    bool operator!=(file_struct_iterator other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
};
```

Comment: @eerorika the *one thing* publicly inheriting `std::iterator` does is provide those defines

Comment: Ah, you're right it actually does work. It wouldn't work in case where the base is dependent on template arguments, which is the case I was thinking of. But your iterator is not a template so that is not a problem. The deprecation of `std::iterator` still applies though.